# Is it possible to make angular server to server requests?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I have an angular application deployed, but when it creates requests it makes all petitions from client to server api's, that is not desirable because it forces me to publish to internet the api server ports

Is it possible to make all petitions internal ?

Comment: what's wrong with publishing the API to the world as long as you using token to identify your client?

Comment: if you want the first requests to come from the server, you could checkout Angular Universal

Comment: @EliPorush its for security requirements

Comment: this is what tokens for